# Playing multiple video streams simultaneously in WP8

Tags: video, windows-phone-8, mmppf

I understand that MediaElement only supports playing one video stream at a time in Windows Phone 8. However, I have a business requirement to play at least two, possible more, streams simultaneously to show a picture-in-picture view from different local (isostore) sources. This works in iOS and Android, but we need to port our application to Windows Phone 8 as well.

I tried the Player Framework from Codeplex, but it seems just to wrap the MediaElement and hence I cannot make it play more than one video stream.

Are there any workarounds to be able to play more than one video stream in a Windows Phone 8 application?

Comment: There isn't any work-around for video at this time, it's a platform limitation.

Comment: Platform limitation such as won't approve to Windows Store or exceed memory or processor boundaries, or just that it hasn't been done yet? I guess it would be possible to port some open library for mp4 decoding and roll my own player but that would seriously exceed the deadline for this project..

Comment: The hardware is capable, but there are currently no system APIs that allow you to achieve this. As you mention, a custom route using C++ should be possible.